# Java websocket with proxy

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, websocket, credentials

I have been trying all day and night for couple of days trying to make websocket to work using proxy in **Java**. I tried different library like

https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client

But sadly these library doesn't support proxy with credentials. If you guys have known any other library that supports proxy then I would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the proxy you are using supports websockets? Many don't. Though many can be tricked into supporting it when you use websockets over TLS (wss://).

Comment: I have tested that proxy in my firefox mozilla for checking websocket and it works. but I wanted to make it work in java program but it seems like quiet complex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** library. It supports authentication at a proxy server. Note that, however, the current implementation supports Basic Authentication only.

```java
// 1. Create a WebSocketFactory instance.
WebSocketFactory factory = new WebSocketFactory();

// 2. Set up information about a proxy server.
//    Credentials can be set here.
ProxySettings settings = factory.getProxySettings();
settings.setServer("http://proxy.example.com");
settings.setCredentials("id", "password");

// 3. Connect to a WebSocket endpoint via the proxy.
WebSocket ws = factory.createSocket("ws://websocket.example.com");

// 4. Add a listener to receive WebSocket events.
ws.addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onTextMessage(WebSocket ws, String message) {
        // Received a text message.
        ......
    }
});

// 5. Perform a WebSocket opening handshake.
ws.connect();

// 6. Send frames.

// 6-1. Text
ws.sendText("Hello.");

// 6-2. Binary
byte[] binary = ......;
ws.sendBinary(binary);

// 6-3. Ping
ws.sendPing("Are you there?");

// 6-4. Pong (unsolicited pong; RFC 6455, 5.5.3. Pong)
ws.sendPong("I'm OK.");

// 6-5. Fragmented Frames
ws.sendText("How ", false)
  .sendContinuation("are ")
  .sendContinuation("you?", true);

// 6-6. Periodical Ping
ws.setPingInterval(60 * 1000);

// 6-7. Periodical Pong (unsolicited pong; RFC 6455, 5.5.3. Pong)
ws.setPongInterval(60 * 1000);

// 6-8. Close (if you want to send one manually).
ws.sendClose(WebSocketCloseCode.NORMAL, "Bye.");

// 7. Disconnect
ws.disconnect();
```

**Blog**
*WebSocket client library (Java SE 1.5+, Android)*
http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/05/websocket-client-library-java-se-15.html

**GitHub**
https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

**JavaDoc**
http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/

**Maven**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
    <artifactId>nv-websocket-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The size of `nv-websocket-client-1.3.jar` is 62,854 bytes and it does not require any external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net) (reference implementation of WebSocket API in Java EE); client side does not require any Java EE server to be running and if you are using Java 7, the client could be [minimized to ~500kb](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/reducing_websocket_client_jar_size).

[Client behing proxy](https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.10/user-guide.html#d0e1323) and [Dependencies](https://tyrus.java.net/dependencies.html) should provide enough info to try.

Comment: I am trying that one right now but it is not working with proxy settings also i need to use credential in proxy

Comment: Proxy auth is not the area which we have much to offer :-/ but! you should be able to use PROXY_HEADERS: https://tyrus.java.net/apidocs/1.10/org/glassfish/tyrus/client/ClientProperties.html#PROXY_HEADERS for basic/digest preemptive auth. If you have more complicated auth scheme (basically anything with challenge), you might need to modify Tyrus code.. (I can help with that, basically the only reason why that is not implemented is that we don't have enough demand for it and the testing setup is complicated..)