# Jupyterhub and nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: nginx, jupyterhub

I was trying to configure the jupyterhub proxy to route the content going to `my-host-ip/notebook` but it i cannot figure out the solution.

I am using the following Nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /notebook {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;

            # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location ~* /(user[-/][a-zA-Z0-9]*)/(api/kernels/[^/]+/(channels|iopub|shell|stdin)|terminals/websocket)/? {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;

            # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            # WebSocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://aptro.github.io/server/architecture/2016/06/21/Jupyter-Notebook-Nginx-Setup.html

Comment: @TarunLalwani do you mean using the same approach because i am using jupyterhub that encapsulate jupyter notebook

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by using the following options with jupyterhub configuration file:

```
# Force the proxy to only listen to connections to 127.0.0.1 
c.JupyterHub.ip = '127.0.0.1'  
c.JupyterHub.base_url = u'/notebook'
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is valid only **if you have another proxy configuration on your client** computer ( if you are using a proxy on your browser or os to access the internet). This failure could be due to a poorly managed proxy by your company/school/telecom provider, reasons explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974731/websockets-not-connected-behind-proxy).

**Solution**

setup a self signed ssl certificate so that the websocket can tunnel through the TLS/SSL connection. Since you already have Nginx installed this is quite easy. Follow [this guide at digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04) to quickly setup a free self signed ssl certificate.

Further you need to add the following header in your nginx websocket config to work.

```
proxy_set_header Origin ""
```