# Slack bot rtm connect fails behind proxy, using python slackclient

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

When running slack bot using proxies `SlackClient.rtm_connect()` fails with below error, where as at the same time api_calls `api.test`, `auth.test` seems working fine, any idea how this can be fixed ? Am i missing some other configuration ?

```
WARNING:slackclient.client:Failed RTM connect
Connection failed. Exception traceback printed above.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slackclient\client.py", line 140, in rtm_connect
    self.server.rtm_connect(use_rtm_start=with_team_state, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slackclient\server.py", line 159, in rtm_connect
    self.connect_slack_websocket(self.ws_url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\slackclient\server.py", line 200, in connect_slack_websocket
    raise SlackConnectionError(message=str(e))
SlackConnectionError: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Below is the code snippet,

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

client_proxies = {"https": "https://127.0.0.1:8080"}

slack_client = SlackClient(token=BOT_TOKEN, proxies=client_proxies)

print slack_client.api_call("api.test")
print slack_client.api_call("auth.test")

slack_client.rtm_connect()
```

api_call `api.test` returned below

```
{u'token': u'TOKEN'}, u'ok': True}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websockets not connected behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974731/websockets-not-connected-behind-proxy)

Comment: Note that RTM uses Websockets, whereas normal API calls use HTTP. So your call to api.test does not prove much.

Comment: Yes, just figured out that http proxy also needed along with https. Its working fine now. Thanks